# jQuery read values and do calculations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html table with 3 rows each row contains two `<td>` one with text input field with `name="freq"` and the second `<td>` is empty.

I want to read all the values of input fields and do calculation function on them then set the results for every field in the empty `<td>`

I want to do that in jQuery,

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this..

```
$('input[name="freq"]').each(function(){
  var value = this.value; // extract the value from the input element
  var newValue = process(value); // process performs the calculations..

  $(this).closest('td').next().html(newValue); // find the following <td> element and set its contents to the result of the calculations..
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/bWFxQ/

Comment: I faced a small problem in calculation, I set the fields value to load default value (15, 10, 20). The first time everything calculated correctly but when I enter different values in the fields the old values still in the memory(session) and the new values multiplied with the old values, I don't figure out how to fix this.

Comment: @YaBasha, can you show your code ? maybe you are not initializing a variable correctly..

Comment: @Ya Basha, can you add the relevant html as i cannot do any tests with just the javascript..

Comment: @gaby-aka-g-petrioli thank you for your help, I've figured out what is the problem, which is: I was doing the calculation with max and min value and I was initialized it with document.ready which means it calculate the max and min once at the start and whenever I changed the values of freq the same max and min value in memory, solution: I  moved the calculation of max and min inside the button script so each time the button is pressed it calculates max and min. Thanx again man.

Comment: @Ya Basha, nice.. glad you sorted it out :)

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
$('#yourTable td[name="freq"] input').change(function(){
  var val = parseInt($(this).val());
  val = val * 3 + 4; //your calculation
  $(this).parent().next().text(val);
});
```

Comment: you may need to use   val = eval(val)+3+4;

Comment: Why ? DO NOT use `eval`. Really.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#table :input').change(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  val = eval(val) * 5; //your calculation
  $(this).parents('td:first').next().html(val);
});
```